# Decreasing size of CGPath with time in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game in which I want a sprite node to follow a circular movement, and with time the circles radius should gradually decrease to zero. I am assuming, this can be done by making a circular path using CGPath() and then decrease the paths radius by 1 point everytime the update() function is called.

Here is the code:

```
func createOrbit() -> (CGPath) {
    let orbitPathOrigin = CGPoint(x: center.x , y: center.y)
    let orbitPathRect = CGRect(origin: orbitPathOrigin, size: orbitSize)
    let orbitPath = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(orbitPathRect, nil)
    return orbitPath
}
```

How do I refer to each of the path that is created and reduce their size?

Comment: Are you trying to create a spiral then? In which case take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427482/moving-a-skspritenode-in-a-downward-loop-using-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best way to do is creating a path and make items follow that path like you mentioned,

So you can make particles follow path like below

```
var mySatellite = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
var spinAction = SKAction.followPath(self.createOrbit(), asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, duration: 4.0)

mySatellite.runAction(spinAction)
```

Set time action somewhere in your `didMoveToView` method or alike,

```
var wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(4.0)
var play = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in
               var newPath = self.decreasedOrbit(20.0)   
               var spinAction = SKAction.followPath(newPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, duration: 4.0)
           }

var waitAndPlaySeq = SKAction.sequence([wait,play])
mySatellite.runAction(waitAndPlaySeq)
```

AssignNewOrbit function to assigning new route to the particle.

`decreasedOrbit` function like below just for only creating new small orbits.

And also you need to decrease the size of orbit for each period

```
   func decreasedOrbit(diameter : CGFloat) -> CGPath{

       var newDiameter = CGFloat(diameter - 5.0)
       var squareRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: newDiameter, height: newDiameter))
       var bezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: squareRect)

       return bezierPath.CGPath
   }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This sounds like it works. Let me update you in a few hours after trying. Thank you for answering though.

Comment: Can you also type the implementation of your function decreaseOrbit( )?

Comment: I've added decreasedOrbit() function too but you can edit origin parameter or decrease size (5.0 in my example).

Comment: @mert, you shouldn't be using `NSTimer` with Sprite Kit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978209/spritekit-creating-a-timer

Comment: @ABakerSmith I've read NSTimer link and you're right It seems that NSTimer is little buggy with SpriteKit. Anyway I've updated my answer take a look please, thanks for the fix :)